# Existence of a function continuous everywhere and nowhere differentialable

Tags: continuity, differential-topology

We know there exists some functions, such that Weierstrass one, that are continuous everywhere on $[0 ; 1]$ and nowhere differentiable. Their expression (and a little bit of work) would yield a proof. 
However, I was wondering if we can just prove the existence of such a function, without finding it. 
I searched on the web and found nothing. Would some of you have a reference or a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's been a while, but I think this is a case where Baire category theorems come into play.

Comment: Thank you I'll check that.

Comment: There is an example using the Baire Category Theorem in "A Primer of Real Functions" by Ralph Boas.